# Why did this postgres database upgrade fail?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to upgrade from Postgresql 9.6 to 10 unsuccessfully.

I ran `brew upgrade postgresql` with success, then ran `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` with failure message. The issue seems to be this line:

`lc_collate values for database "postgres" do not match:  old "en_GB.UTF-8", new "en_US.UTF-8"`

The whole message was:

```
    ==> Upgrading postgresql data from 9.6 to 10...
Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
==> Moving postgresql data from /usr/local/var/postgres to /usr/local/var/postgres.o
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "jbkimac".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start

Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is the install user                  ok
Checking database connection settings                       ok
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok
Checking for reg* data types in user tables                 ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch       ok
Checking for invalid "unknown" user columns                 ok
Creating dump of global objects                             ok
Creating dump of database schemas
                                                            ok

lc_collate values for database "postgres" do not match:  old "en_GB.UTF-8", new "en_US.UTF-8"
Failure, exiting
Error: Upgrading postgresql data from 9.6 to 10 failed!
==> Removing empty postgresql initdb database...
==> Moving postgresql data back from /usr/local/var/postgres.old to /usr/local/var/p
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_upgrade -r -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin -B /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres.old -D /usr/local/var/postgres -j 8` exited with 1.
```

Can anyone help advise me as to how to fix this `"en_GB.UTF-8", new "en_US.UTF-8"` conflict issue?

Comment: I think you need to change `LC_COLLATE` to `en_GB.UTF-8` before running `pg_upgrade` so that the new cluster is initialized with the same collation as the old one

Comment: `initdb --lc-collate="en_GB.UTF-8" -D /usr/local/var/postgres` successful and confirms that the cluster will be initialized with en_GB, then I run `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` and same issue. Apologies I'm a newbie to this, can you advise. Thanks

Comment: please try `export LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8` before `initdb` and also use `locale=en_GB.UTF-8` with `initdb`

Comment: If you're using `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` You'll have to change file `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/cmd/brew-postgresql-upgrade-database.rb `, line `system "#{bin}/initdb", "#{var}/postgres"` to include ` "--local=en_GB.UTF-8"` or whatever is appropriate becuase the writter never included options to change those settings in the script, maybe I should add this as a PR?

Comment: @Thermatix, could you say a little more specifically what needs to added where?

Comment: Oh wow, this was a while ago, you just need to search for the line that has `system "#{bin}/initdb", "#{var}/postgres"` and add to the line `", --local=en_GB.UTF-8"` or whatever encoding you specifically need.

Answer (score 12):

```
brew services stop postgresql
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
brew services start postgresql
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit of text explaining why OP was getting his error, and how those commands fix that?

Comment: The question is, **Why did this postgres database upgrade fail?** and a code dump does not answer that question.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` and had to change `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/cmd/brew-postgresql-upgrade-database.rb` as @Thermatix mentioned. Both `--lc-collate` and `--lc-ctype` have to correspond with the current database settings. In my case `ch_DE.UTF8` for both.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old but just in case it can help someone: the default databases might not have been initialized with the right `lc_ctype` **and** `lc_collate`. It's *really* simple to overlook the error message and try to fix the wrong setting.

To do it step by step (without `brew postgresql-upgrade-database`) :

- Just in case, save your current database schema (with `pg_dumpall` for example) and move the data folder into another location (by default it's `/usr/local/var/posgres`)
- Then, initialize the default DB with the latest version :

  ```
  $ initdb --lc-collate=en_GB.UTF-8 --lc-ctype=en_GB.UTF-8 -E UTF-8 /usr/local/var/postgres
  ```
- Finally import your old data into the new version's data folder (here from PG 13 to 14):

  ```
  $ /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.1_1/bin/pg_upgrade
    -r
    -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@13/13.5_1/bin/
    -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.1_1/bin/
    -d /usr/local/var/postgres.old
    -D /usr/local/var/postgres
    -j 4
  ```